# Retaining "<" while applying XSLT to an xml

Tags: xml, cocoa, xslt, xml-parsing

I am using the XML->XHTL conversion for printing a model based window.
What I do is to convert my model into a well formed xml. And then applying xsl to it.

A few attributes in my model have large text value. Occasionally this text may contain, "<" and ">". Whenever such text appears, the text between "<" and ">" is skipped.
For example, if my text is "`This <item name> belongs to me.`"
The output I get is "`This belongs to me.`" <item name> is skipped. It looks like these characters in the attribute's value are also identified as the beginning and end of xml tags. They get converted to &lt; and &gt;. And so the value is not printed.

Can anyone please tell me, how can i retain the angular brackets in the attribute's value in output as well?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Sahitya

P.S.-I am a newbie to xml handling and xsl as well.

XML with the CData section:
    "`<descriptionText><![CDATA[This <item name> belongs to me.]]></descriptionText>`"

XSL excerpt:
    `<tr><td><xsl:value-of select="descriptionText" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></td></tr>`

expectedOutput:
    `This <item name> belongs to me.`

ActualOutput:
    `This  belongs to me.`

**EDIT:**

For implementing the print functionality at the application level, I am using the APIs of WebFrameLoadDelegate and NSPrintOperation.
Once the webview is created successfully, the delegate API,

`- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame;`

of the printer class, is called.
Please see the implementation of this API below:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
{
    NSPrintInfo *pi = [NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo];
    if ([NSPrintInfo defaultPrinter])
    {
        [pi setPrinter:[NSPrintInfo defaultPrinter]]; 
    }
    [pi setTopMargin:5.0];
    [pi setLeftMargin:5.0];
    [pi setBottomMargin:10.0];
    [pi setRightMargin:5.0];
    [pi setHorizontalPagination:NSFitPagination];
    [pi setVerticalPagination:NSFitPagination];
    [pi setVerticallyCentered:YES];
    [pi setHorizontallyCentered:YES];
    [[self.webView preferences] setAutosaves: NO];
    [[self.webView preferences] setShouldPrintBackgrounds:YES];
    NSPrintOperation *printOperation = [[[self.webView mainFrame] frameView] printOperationWithPrintInfo:pi];
    [printOperation runOperationModalForWindow:self.window delegate:self.delegate didRunSelector:self.callbackSelector contextInfo:nil];
}
```

Comment: :O it happened here also. In the example, i wrote "This <item name> belongs to me. But when i posted, <item name> has been skipped.

Also, I forgot to mention in the question, that I have tried encapsulating the value in CDATA section also. It was also not useful.

Comment: One of the several serious shortcomings of HTML/XML is the lack of a decent "bulk" escaping mechanism for strings.  You generally must pre-process the text to replace the `<>` characters with their `&` equivalents.

Comment: Show some code that you've tried.  Particularly you attempt to encapsulate in CDATA section, as that's the correct approach.

Comment: Sahitya, the less than sign `<` needs to be escaped in XML, unless it is used to mark up things. So `<foo bar="a &lt; b"/>` is well-formed XML but `<foo bar="a < b"/>` is not. As for 'retaining "<"', it is not clear what you want to achieve, post a sample of the well-formed XML input you have, a sample of the XSLT code, a sample of the XHTML output you want and a sample of the one you get, then we can suggest how to fix the XSLT.

Comment: I cannot believe that `<item name>` would have been skipped by the XSLT process, since it is not valid XML; the attribute `name` has invalid format and there is no closing `</item>` tag. I would expect you to get a malformed XML input error. As for your problem itself, as other commenters have said, use `CDATA`, which actually is a perfectly decent "bulk" escaping mechanism.

Comment: You need to need more about XML and read. The W3C XML Specification mandates escaping the following two characters in an attribute value: `&` and `<`. They are represented by `&amp;` and `&lt;`. **This is only a representation -- the characters aren't modified and are still the `&` and `<` characters**. Therefore there is nothing tragic in having these characters escaped.

Comment: @MartinHonnen..I have added the xml, xsl excerpt, and the actual & expected outputs. Please let me know if I should post more information.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev..So does that mean that if the vlue of an attribute, like in my case, contains an "`<`" or "`&`", they wont come as it is in the output. If that is so, it'll be a disappointment :(

Comment: @SLaks -- CDATA only sorta works, some of the time.

Comment: Where are you viewing the output, and why are you disabling output escaping?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams..As I said in my question, I am using this XML -> XHTML conversion mechanism to print a model based window, I am viewing the output in the print preview (Opened with Preview on Mac).

As for the DOE, I used it based on a few resources i found online, in an attempt to retain the "<" in the output.

Comment: @HotLicks, please educate me, at what times and in what ways does CDATA not work?

Comment: @SahityaTarumani, now you can accept the best answer for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you

1. Wrap the text containing `<` and `&` in `CDATA` in your XML input
2. Do *not* use `disable-output-escaping`

Then the output of `This <item name> belongs to me` will be `This &lt;item name&gt; belongs to me`, which the browser will display correctly as `This <item name> belongs to me.`

If you turn *on* `disable-output-escaping`, then the HTML generated will be `This <item name> belongs to me`, and the browser will think `<item name>` is an undefined HTML tag and skip over it, as you describe.

**Edit**

Here is a fully-functioning example:

**simple.xml (input)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="simple.xslt"?>
<simple>
    <![CDATA[This <item name> belongs to me.]]>
</simple>
```

**simple.xslt**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output** (when xml is opened in browser)

```
This <item name> belongs to me.
```

Comment: @torazaburo... Tried that...Didnt work, i still get `This belongs to me`

Comment: @SahityaTarumani Then you'll need to provide the complete input XML, XSLT and HTML output of a test case which reproduces the problem.

Comment: i think u can reproduce the issue on any xsl editor with the data in my question... :|

Comment: The data in your question is *wrong*, because it contains `disable-output-escaping`, but you need to turn that OFF (*remove* it). In other words, the XSLT excerpt should read `<tr><td><xsl:value-of select="descriptionText"/></td></tr>`.

Comment: Without the DOE also, I get the same results. (i.e., with the excerpt you have suggested)

Comment: If you want me or anyone else on SO to help you, you need to edit your question and provide the full input XML, XSLT, and its HTML output.

Comment: I am still working on this. The example u have given, works on an xslt editor that i found online (w3schools). However, What I am trying is to use the webView thus created for printing. And I do not get the desired results there.

Comment: Here is what I am trying: I am working on a cocoa based application.
I have a window that has a model, which populates the data. In order to facilitate printing, I convert this model's attributes and relationships to an xml format, which is pretty much the same as simple.xml (with a lot more nodes for the different attrs and rels. Its the same for descriptionText node though).My xsl also looks similar to simple.xslt (again with a lot more rows).

Comment: Now when the model->xml conversion happens, I have 
`<simple>
    <![CDATA[This <item name> belongs to me.]]>
</simple>`
but in the print preview, I see `This belongs to me.`

I still dont understand why it works on the browser, but the same is different in a print preview.

Can you think of any reason?

Comment: @SahityaTarumani Do you mean the print preview of the browser? Which browser? It works fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: no no...not of the browser...i am implementing the "print" function for my application.

Comment: Then the bug is in your print function. I guess you should close this question, and post a new one, providing as much information as possible about what your are doing.

Comment: Why close this question and post the same question again?? I have edited the question to give details of the implementation of the print functionality. It uses the basic APIs of WebFrameLoadDelegate, and NSPrintOperation. As I mentioned earlier, this is a cocoa based application. I am making use of the NSPrintOperation class's APIs to execute the print operation, after the webView is created.
If I go by what you say, the webview should have the correct data (i.e, `This <item name> belongs to me.`). The mistake then should be in the new piece of code that I've posted. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have angle brackets in HTML text, they need to be escaped as > and <. I expect that the CDATA section is solving the problem in converting to HTML but when you view the HTML the browser is ignoring the tag it doesn't understand.

Comment: Can you think of any workaround for this? There is a high probability that the text I am working with will contain the angular brackets. Is there no way they can be obtained in the output?